# How to stop function if input is invalid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to get a value of several URL input and if value of URL isn't not valid, I just want to animate input element and stop everything.

Is there any way to do it?

```
$('button').click(function(e){
  var linkarr = [];
  var $input = $('.default');
  var isValidUrl = /[0-9a-z_-]+\.[0-9a-z_-][0-9a-z]/; // URLvalid check

  $input.each(function() {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    if(!isValidUrl.test(inputVal)) {
      $(this).parent().animateCss('shake');
   // if input is not valid, I want to stop the code here.
    }
    if(inputVal) linkarr.push(inputVal);
  });

  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/api/compress',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {url: linkarr},
    success: function(data){ something
  });
});
```

Comment: to abort a .each() loop, simply `return false` inside the each handler.

Comment: Maybe you should be more specific? If *any* of the URL's are invalid, do you then want to not do the ajax call, or just stop the iteration, or just don't push that URL to the array, or what ?

Comment: @MarcB If Url is not valid I don't want to execute ajax form. so what I'm trying to do is stop everything.

Comment: @adeneo don't call the ajax if it's not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to let outside of your each loop know the condition of the contents.

```
$('button').click(function(e){
  var linkarr = [];
  var $input = $('.default');
  var isValidUrl = /[0-9a-z_-]+\.[0-9a-z_-][0-9a-z]/; // URLvalid check
  var blnIsValid = true;

  $input.each(function() {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    if(!isValidUrl.test(inputVal)) {
      $(this).parent().animateCss('shake');
      // if input is not valid, I want to stop the code here.
      // Input isn't valid so stop the code
      blnIsValid = false;
      return false; // Alternatively don't stop so that any other invalid inputs are marked
    } 

    if(inputVal) linkarr.push(inputVal);
  });

  e.preventDefault();

  // Check to make sure input is valid before making ajax call
  if (blnIsValid) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/compress',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: {url: linkarr},
      success: function(data){ something
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is you can use flag to check and execute the Ajax method

```js
$('button').click(function(e){
  var linkarr = [];
  var $input = $('.default');
  var isValidUrl = /[0-9a-z_-]+\.[0-9a-z_-][0-9a-z]/; // URLvalid check
  var callAjax = true;

  $input.each(function() {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    if(!isValidUrl.test(inputVal)) {
      $(this).parent().animateCss('shake');
      callAjax  = false;
      return false;
   // if input is not valid, I want to stop the code here.
    }
    if(inputVal) linkarr.push(inputVal);
  });

  e.preventDefault();
  if(callAjax)
    {
   $.ajax({
    url: '/api/compress',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {url: linkarr},
    success: function(data){ something
  });
    }
});
```